# Multisig Sapling - Taquito

Tags: smartpy, taquito, multisig

Title is presenting the idea here:

Using shielded pool:
Trying to make a transactions: 
From alice -> to bob 
Approved by a third party (admin)

NomadicLabs defined it in their docs however, not able to find any code example yet : https://opentezos.com/tezos-basics/sapling/#example-without-monitoring-of-the-transaction-by-a-third-party

Where should this be handled, on the contract side (SmartPy here) what about front end actions for the admin sapling @taquito/sapling is not providing infos for multisig in sapling

Answer (score 2):

The third party the documentation from Nomadic Labs talks about is a backend service that receives requests to forge and sign the transactions with its own key in order to make the transactions even more anonymous before sending them to the Sapling contract.
In this scenario, only one account ever interacts with the Sapling contract. The tooling to set up that kind of service already exists, and it would be ideal to make the transactions 100% anonymous, but it also increases your chances to be arrested if you live in the Netherlands or in a country with a like-minded government :)

Answer (score 1):

I can provide some resources that maybe can help?
There is a Sapling [Guide](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZBqtv4FnJP8S7vwHXvGRjipDVuok5szDoCcunx4VDD8P)

Taquito also released a high-level API for Sapling this year.

Checkout:
- [Sapling Toolkit](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZBqtv4FnJP8S7vwHXvGRjipDVuok5szDoCcunx4VDD8P) and [Using Sapling with Taquito. An overview of using Sapling](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZBqtv4FnJP8S7vwHXvGRjipDVuok5szDoCcunx4VDD8P)

Maybe worth to mention that probably in some time Sapling for tokens will be available too, if you want to include this in your design idea:
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/4488

Comment: Thanks for your response Zitar

Looked at the Taquito documentation already, it mentioned Transfer from A to B but not third party interaction.

Am I out of the scope with this idea ?

Comment: Hey @AlexOuille an you please be a bit more precise with your usecase/example you would like to achieve? As I and others do not fully understand the question but want to help! Just edit the original question and try to describe it a bit more precisely. Thanks!

Comment: Updated and added the document from nomadic labs explaining how a third party could interact in a sapling transaction